# Insert rows based on another row

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a row in my table and I need insert other similar rows if they don't exist. For example column SubKey1 = XFITEST and column SubKey2 = 5. I need to check if there is a row with column SubKey1 = XFITEST and Column SubKey2 = 7 and if not I need to insert it.  Basically I need to check every SubKey1 that has a Subkey2 = 5 and make sure it also has a row with the same SubKey1 but SubKey2 = 7 and if not I need to insert it.

Thanks!

Edit: Hopefully a good example.  In the below example I need to identify that Subkey1 XFITEST is missing a row that has a subkey2 of 7 and insert it.

This is what I currently have. There are a whole bunch of different value in Subkey1 that I need to check though.

[image: IMG1]

```
SubKey1   SubKey2
AISBTF500   5
AISBTF500   7
XFITEST     5
```

This is what I am trying to accomplish.

```
SubKey1   SubKey2
AISBTF500   5
AISBTF500   7
XFITEST     5
XFITEST     7
```

Comment: Could you explain more detail for your question I don't know what's the logic

Comment: Could you provide some sample data and expect result? that really help

Comment: I would urge you to read your question and ask yourself if YOU would be able to answer this based only on what you posted. Then I would urge you to read this. https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql

Comment: Yeah, I am struggling to figure out how to explain it.  I will work on the question.

Comment: Images are not good for sample data or table structures. Why? https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557

Comment: @KellyPeterson The best way to explain data transformations is with data - some well formatting input data and expected result as text virtually always clears things up. https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: The best thing you can do is post ddl (create table statement(s)) and sample data (insert statements) along with the desired output. It is tough to learn how to ask well formatted questions.

Comment: Please, when pasting pictures, use in-line format: `![IMG1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/54jCz.png)`. But in your case it's better off paste text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[SQL HERE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/9d098/3)

You can do it like below :

```
insert into Table1(SubKey1, SubKey2)
    select SubKey1, 7 as SubKey2 from Table1 as tbl1
        where SubKey2=5 and 
            not exists(select 1 from Table1 where SubKey1=tbl1.SubKey1 and SubKey2=7)
    group by SubKey1, SubKey2
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `not exists` with `insert into .... select` to make it.

the get the `SubKey1` which didn't have `SubKey2 = 7` name. then insert it.

```
create table t(
   SubKey1 varchar(50),
   SubKey2 int
);


insert into t values ('AISBTF500',5);
insert into t values ('AISBTF500',7);
insert into t values ('XFITEST',5);

INSERT INTO T (SubKey1,SubKey2)
SELECT SubKey1,7
FROM T t1
WHERE not exists (
  SELECT 1 
  FROM T tt
  WHERE tt.SubKey2 = 7 and tt.SubKey1 = t1.SubKey1
)
```

**Query 1**:

```
select * from t
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/9463a/1/0)**:

```
|   SubKey1 | SubKey2 |
|-----------|---------|
| AISBTF500 |       5 |
| AISBTF500 |       7 |
|   XFITEST |       5 |
|   XFITEST |       7 |
```

Comment: If I also wanted to add rows for an additional subkey2 like 8 for example, is it best to run this again and just change SELECT SubKey1,7 to SELECT SubKey1,8. Or is there a better way?

Comment: Yes run this again  or your can use `UNION ALL` http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/b61a4b/1 to combine all result set then insert

Comment: When I try and run this across a wider scope on my table I get a PK constraint that it says I am trying to insert a dup, Subkey1 and Subkey 2 are both part of the PK.  Thing is, when I check it doesn't already exist.  Any thoughts?  Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_Mvpr'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.Mvpr'. The duplicate key value is (S, ACD1, 7, , 0.00)

Comment: This is the statement I am trying to run.                                                   INSERT INTO dbo.mvpr (prefix,A2,SubKey1,SubKey2)
SELECT prefix,'1.57',SubKey1,'7'
FROM DBO.MVPR t1
WHERE not exists (
  SELECT 1 
  FROM DBO.MVPR tt
  WHERE tt.SubKey2 = '7' and tt.SubKey1 = t1.SubKey1
) AND T1.PREFIX = 'S'